# Showing a subset to be a subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $$G=\{T\in GL(n;\mathbb{R})~|~T^tST=S, ~\text{for all skew-symmetric matrix}~S\in\mathbb{M}(n;\mathbb{R}))\}$$ where $ GL(n;\mathbb{R})$ is the space of all $n\times n$ invertible matrices and $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of all $n\times n$ matrices.

Now I can show that $I$, the identity matrix is in $G$. Also if $A,B\in G$, then $AB\in G$ [as for any skew symmetric matrix $S$, and any matrix $T$, $T^tST$ is also a kew symmetric matrix].

Only if I can show that

> $A\in G$ implies $A^{-1}\in G$

I could show that $G$ is a subgroup of $GL(n;\mathbb{R})$. How can I show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A \in G$.  Then for any skew-symmetric matrix $S$, we have
$$
(A^{-1})^TS(A^{-1}) = \\
(A^{-1})^T[A^T SA](A^{-1}) = \\
[(A^T)^{-1}A^T] S[AA^{-1}] =\\
S
$$
Since this holds for all skew-symmetric $S$, we conclude that $A^{-1} \in G$.